# Is there a standard, cross-platform way to handle and store relative file paths?

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, cross-platform, filepath

I am writing a Firefox add-on that stores and opens files stored within a base directory (a directory that the user selects as a preference).  I would like to make it easy for the user to copy that directory and move it to another computer (possibly switching between OSX, Linux and Windows).

The first way I thought to do this was just to store the part of the file path after the base directory, and, if the operating system is Windows, to change all \'s to /'s.  Then when using the path, the stored path is concatenated onto the current base directory (after replacing all /'s with \'s if the operating system is Windows).

Is this reasonable or a bad practice?  If someone used a \ in an OSX path (I think that's possible, but maybe those slashes are some other character that looks like the file separator character \?), it could lead to unwanted behavior.  One alternative I thought of was to use nsIFile and build the relative path by recursively using parent and leafName to pick out each directory name and save it to a string with something like "" in between, which I could then replace with the appropriate path separator for the operating system.  This seems more robust than my first method, but maybe there is a simpler, more standard solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to invent your own solution, there is [`nsILocalFile.getRelativeDescriptor()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsILocalFile#getRelativeDescriptor%28%29). Example:

```
var file1 = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/file/local;1"]
                      .createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsILocalFile);
file1.initWithPath("c:\\foo\\");

var file2 = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/file/local;1"]
                      .createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsILocalFile);
file2.initWithPath("c:\\foo\\bar\\test.txt");
alert(file2.getRelativeDescriptor(file1));
```

This code will display `bar/test.txt`. To get from a relative descriptor to a file you use `setRelativeDescriptor()`:

```
file2.setRelativeDescriptor(file1, "bar/test.txt");
alert(file2.path);
```

The relative descriptors are cross-platform, you can move the directory do a different OS and the descriptor won't change.

Comment: Thanks!  I read through the nsIFile documentation, but I missed the links to nsILocalFile.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean to hit enter....  Your examples show how to use a full path on a base path to generate and store a relative path and then how recreate a full path from a base path and the stored relative path.  There is one other thing that I would want to do and that is to generate a relative path programmatically.  Is the best way to do that to run append() on the base path recursively for each directory level and then use getRelativeDescriptor() (rather than just generating a relative path string like "bar/test.txt")?

Comment: @ws_e_c421: It should be a safe assumption that the format of the relative descriptor won't change. So you can probably just use `"bar/test.txt"` if you have a constant relative descriptor.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this in my searches. There's a new solution now. It's OS.File: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript_OS.File/OS.File_for_the_main_thread